# Checking if the user has entered a string that is inside of an array

Tags: c++

So, I'm trying to have it so that if you type one of the strings from the colours array it checks again if the colour is orange..

```
if (find(begin(colours[0], colours[6])) != askAnswer) {
    if (askAnswer == "orange" || askAnswer == "Orange")
    {
        cout << "I love that colour too!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Eh, that colour is alright.." << endl;
    }
} else {
    cout << "Eh.. What's that??";
}
```

Comment: `find(begin(colours[0], colours[6]))` is wrong. Maybe you wanted `find(begin(colours), end(colours), askAnswer) != end(colours)` instead.

Comment: yeah, did that.. this is the stack: http://gyazo.com/0471877626e798b5f70fa6c413675cc8 - sorry, i just took a little picture of it

Comment: What about finding "oRanGe"?  In other words, you should *transform* the text to all upper case or all lower case before comparing.

Comment: @Noah you never posted `colours`. It seems like you have it as `std::string *colours[6];`? In that case, change it to `std::vector<std::string> colours;` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using find the wrong way. take a look at the doc: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/
You probably wanted

```
if (find(colours, colours+7, askAnswer) != colours+7)
```

where 7 is size of your array (which means `colours+7` is an invalid pointer pointing to "one after last" element ). 
But it would be better to use std::begin() and std::end() as below:

```
if (find(std::begin(colours), std::end(colours), askAnswer) != std::end(colours))
```

Also - take a look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end#Example

Comment: it says 'ast' has not been declared

Comment: typoo.. supposed to be std